# Error Code @5fa01e33 in Java, Resulting from Access Google API Data

Tags: java, api, gdata

i'm having trouble with java programming. This java is calling Google API which provide me with GData access

I'm having trouble when it's querying some query, resulting @5fa01e33. This is my code:

```
    package com.thegroovie;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.google.gdata.client.DocumentQuery;
import com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListFeed;

public class GDataExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Username");
    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Password");

    try{
        DocsService service = new DocsService("Document List demo");
        service.setProtocolVersion(DocsService.Versions.V3);
        service.setUserCredentials(username, password);

        URL documentListFeedUrl = new
            URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full");

        DocumentListFeed feed = service.getFeed(documentListFeedUrl, DocumentListFeed.class);

        for(DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()){
            System.out.println(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        String input_query = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Search : ");
        DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery(documentListFeedUrl);
        query.setFullTextQuery(input_query);
        DocumentListFeed feeds = service.getFeed(query, DocumentListFeed.class);
        System.out.print(feeds);        
      } 
    catch (Exception ex){
          System.err.println("Exception "+ ex.getMessage());
      }
    }


}
```

How to resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look like as an error code. Rather you print the `DocumentListFeed` object which type doesn't have an overridden `toString` method. You can access the feed's contents with the appropriate accessor methods described in the docs.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I just realize that the script cannot printed using toString or system.out.print